# Trouble running the sample implementation of stripe for React/Node.js Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to press a "checkout" button and have it send me to the stripe checkout page through their sample implementation of stripe for React/node.js

How I installed/ran the sample code.
Steps:

1. Created new react app with vite.
2. Copy/pasted the backend into a new file named server.js
3. copy/pasted frontend without css into a new file named server.jsx
4. node server.js to run the server.
5. started the application (localhost:3000)
6. Pressed checkout button -> console displays: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

I am not sure what to do or how I should go about debugging this. This is my first time trying to do anything related to the backend. I have an idea of how the frontend/backend should interact and I'm assuming its an environment issue or an issue with how I ran the application which is why I listed my steps.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions on what I can do.

backend Server.js

```
// This is your test secret API key.
const stripe = require('stripe')('SKTEST_KEY');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
const {Price, ItemDescription} = req.body;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
        price: 10000,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?success=true`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,
    automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

Frontend
App.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ProductDisplay = () => (
  <section>
    <div className="product">
      <img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
        alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
      />
      <div className="description">
      <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
      <h5>$20.00</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
      <button type="submit">
        Checkout
      </button>
    </form>
  </section>
);

const Message = ({ message }) => (
  <section>
    <p>{message}</p>
  </section>
);

export default function StripeApp() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check to see if this is a redirect back from Checkout
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    if (query.get("success")) {
      setMessage("Order placed! You will receive an email confirmation.");
    }

    if (query.get("canceled")) {
      setMessage(
        "Order canceled -- continue to shop around and checkout when you're ready."
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return message ? (
    <Message message={message} />
  ) : (
    <ProductDisplay />
  );
}
```